# Quero obter o mesmo ID

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase

Boa tarde 
Queria saber se é possível obter o ID  do telemóvel para as mesmas funções ou como no exemplo abaixo.
Quero colocar o ID que esta sinalizado de preto de baixo do "SMS".
È possível colocar?
Como posso fazer?
Mais abaixo encontra-se o código.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private static final String TAG = FirebaseDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public TelaPolicia(){
  demoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

}

public void createUserInFirebaseDatabase(String userId, FirebaseUserEntity firebaseUserEntity){
    Map<String, FirebaseUserEntity> user = new HashMap<String, FirebaseUserEntity>();
    user.put(userId, firebaseUserEntity);
    demoRef.child("SMS").setValue(user);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi exatamente qual  o seu problema, mas notei que você está usando `setValue`, isso vai remover toda a informação já contida no nó 'SMS' e colocar a atual, e pelo que você falou aí, não é isso que quer.

Comment: Além disso: Porquê que você colocou a tag javascript na sua pergunta? A pergunta parece estar relacionada com o Android só.